# Message: Unknown path components: /touchcontrol:watch

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-opengraph

im trying to post the action 'watch' to a object 'video'

getting this error:

```
Error occured

Type: OAuthException

Message: Unknown path components: /touchcontrol:watch
```

Im very desperate!! please help!, Could it have something to do with my OG settings in my app?

Ive seen a previous question about this, but the solution did not fix my code.. still getting the same error

heres my code:

```
function postAction() {
                FB.api('/me/namespace:watch' + '?video="video url"', 'post', function (response) {
                    var msg = 'Error occured';
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        if (response.error) {
                            msg += "\n\nType: " + response.error.type + "\n\nMessage: " + response.error.message;
                        }
                        alert(msg);
                    } else {
                        alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

meta tags:

```
xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="[idnumber]" />
<meta property="og:title" content="titlesomething" />
<meta property="og:image" content="imageurl.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="MyDescription" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://url.com">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="contentname" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.watches" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that definitely the code you're using to post?
Assuming the app's namespace is 'touchcontrol' and the action type is 'watch' that should be correct - does that match what the 'get code' link in the app's OG settings says?

Comment: Custom _watch_ actions won’t get approved any more anyways. And if it’s not a custom one, but the build-in one – then it has to be published against `/me/{objecttype}.watches`